# Finite abelian group has a subgroup $H$ with cyclic quotient that "preserves" the order in the quotient.

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, abelian-groups, alternative-proof, sylow-theory

> **Theorem.** Let $G$ be a finite abelian group and $g \in G$. Then $G$ contains a subgroup $H$ such that $G/H$ is cyclic and the order of $gH$ in $G/H$ is the same as the order of $g$ in $G$.

*Sketch of the proof*. Write $G \simeq \oplus_p G_p$ where $G_p$ is a $p$-Sylow of $G$ and write $G_p \simeq \oplus_r \mathbb{Z}/p^{i_r}\mathbb{Z}$. So, define $H_p \leq G_p$ as direct sum of some $\mathbb{Z}/p^{i_r}\mathbb{Z}$ (there is some important details to do that) and take $H = \oplus_p H_p$.

---

That is the idea of the book "Class Field Theory" by Nancy Childress. I don't know if it is possible, but I would like to know if there is some different proof. Maybe it is not the best way to describe, but I would like to see a "less constructive" proof. Anyway, I appreciate any references.

Comment: Could you clarify? Constructive is actually a plus in situations like this, I would think. Are you perhaps not “seeing” what is going on in the proof, and would like to get more of the idea behind the construction? Or are you hoping for a slick proof even if it seems more magical than explanatory?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I have no problems with this proof and, as you said, probably this is the most natural idea for statments like that. But, by curiosity, I would like to know if there is some proof more "magical", without the need of to show who is $H$.

Comment: I can imagine a proof by induction on $|G|$: find a nontrivial subgroup $H$ that does not intersect $\langle g\rangle$, and then look at $G/H$. The key would just be to show that if all nontrivial subgroups intersect $\langle g\rangle$ then $G$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s an inductive proof.

It suffices to prove this for abelian $p$-groups (do each $p$-part separately, then take their direct sums).

Let $G$ be abelian of order $p^n$, $g\in G$, and assume the result holds for any abelian groups of order $p^k$, $k\lt n$. If $G$ is cyclic, take $H=\{e\}$ and we are done.

If $G$ is not cyclic, then it has more than one subgroup of order $p$. As $\langle g\rangle$ contains at most one subgroup of order $p$, let $H$ be a subgroup of order $p$ with $H\cap\langle g\rangle = \{e\}$. Then $gH$ has the same order in $G/H$ as $g$ has in $G$, and $|G/H|\lt |G|$. Inductively, $G/H$ has a subgroup $M/H$ such that $G/M \cong (G/H)/(M/H)$ is cyclic, and the order of $(gH)M = gM$ in $G/M$ is the same as the order of $gH$ in $G/H$, which is the same as the order of $g\in G$. $\Box$

Comment: It's a great answer. Thanks Arturo!